# facebook c# sdk comments on Photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used Facebook c# sdk to upload photo and it is working well.

I want to add comments on photo uploaded earlier.

can someone please provide code using facebook c# sdk?

Thanks in advance

Brijesh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a c# developer, but according to the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) (comments connection, Create part):

> You can write to the PHOTO_ID/comments connection to post a comment to
>   the photo by issuing an HTTP POST request with the publish_stream
>   permission

All you need to do is to issue an http (POST) request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID/comments?message=COMMENT_MESSAGE_TEXT
```

The different facebook sdks give you the ability to do this with out the need to get messy with http requests, and the c# one probably does not differ.
Just use it to make a (POST) graph request for the path "/PHOTO_ID/comments" with the parameter "message".

Comment: Hi Nitzan, you are right but i need code from  C share SDK as this is what i an using at the moment.